# Hibernate JPA persistance method to use optimistic transactional semantics

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In the API org.apache.openjpa.persistence Interface OpenJPAEntityManager specifices

```
  void  setOptimistic(boolean opt) 
      Whether to use optimistic transactional semantics. method
```

I am looking for similar method or in any way to mention to set optimistic as "false" using Hibernate Persistence. I went through the API and the google not able to find out. Any body please help on this.

Comment: Did you have a look here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html ?  Do you always want to disable optimitistic locking or case-by-case?

Comment: Yes I want always disable optimistic locking

Comment: In that case just don't provide a `@Version` property to your entities. If you can't have a look here on how to disable it per entity (if you want to do it globally just disable it for all entities): http://jeeva-paramasamy.blogspot.de/2012/10/disable-hibernate-optimistic-lock-for.html

Comment: Hi Thanks. In that case my current code is like this: ClientSession session = null;
  EntityManager em = null;
 
  try {
   em = EntityManagerHelper.createEntityManager(EntityManagerHelper.SCHEMA);
  
   if(em!= null){
    session = em.find(ClientSession.class, sessionId);
    if(session != null) {
    // em.setOptimistic(false);

     em.getTransaction().begin();


Here ClientSession means Entity class how to add setOptimisticeLocked(false) also my clientsession don't have version will it works